# Passing self class to parent generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a parent class that needs to store a reference to the instantiating child class for some method.  To do this I'm enforcing a generic in the constructor of the parent class.

```
public abstract class Parent<T> {
    Class<T> clazz;

    public Parent(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

In the child class, I'm extending the parent class with the same child type generic enforced.

```
public class Child extends Parent<Child> {
    public Child() {
        super(Child.class);
    }
}
```

Does this look weird to anyone else?  I feel like the child class is so redundant, since I'm reusing the same type in the generic and in the constructor, which is the same type as the calling class.

Comment: No thats fine, this pattern is typically used with generics. Of course the actual question is why you need that class in this way. Might be a layering violation.

Answer (score -2):

While this does look weird to me, it will not have the desired affect, as you are not asking for the parent when creating the child class, you are simply extending a parent object.

to fix this, you should have the parent as a parameter for the child class.

Something like this;

```
public class Parent{
//Put something here to keep track of the children
//You could use a HashMap, or an ArrayList
private ArrayList<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
     public void registerChild(Child child){
           children.add(child);   
     }
}

public class Child {
    public Child(Parent parent) {
        parent.registerChild(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be making a lot of presumptions about OP's intent.

Comment: Fair, though the code given will do what the OP wanted, and as I stated, to best of my knowledge(which is admitted not huge) the OP code will not call back the parent that called it. It will create a new object of the parent which it is extending. thus the child class can not register itself with the parent.